# Knowledge tab invisible for customer community profile user

Tags: knowledge, customer-community

I have been trying to accomplish below and tired of trying. Please help me.

I am trying to setup a customer community which should display knowledge tab and other custom object tabs.

Knowledge base is activated for the org.

I have enabled Knowledge tab for the custom profile which has been closed from customer community user profile.

All the custom tabs are visible but not the Knowledge tab.

I dont want to give create access for articles. Just want the external users access the articles.

Because I have only one knowledge license.

Kindly help me find a way to achieve it.

Thanks,
Venky

Comment: I know you probably checkef, but is the tab itself set to hidden, rather than default on/default off?

Comment: It is set to default on Meighan. :( Tried in and out. donno whats wrong

Comment: Did you make sure that the Community Profile has Read access to the Knowledge Article Type / Data Category itself? Every time you create a new article type, it creates a custom object for that Article Type. So for instance, one of my systems Article Types is called 'Installs'. I can find it in the Object CRED list as Profiles__kav, and it has Read/Create/Edit/Delete permissions. Check those

Answer (score 1):

I would check the following for the tab to be visible:

1. The profile has read access to knowledge
2. The profile has the tab either Default On or Default off
3. Enable to read permission for the article types you want top share on the profile
4. You added the tab to the community
5. You selected edit profiles and activated the profile on the detail page
6. You assigned the correct profile to the user
7. The profile has access Knowledge One checked (App Settings)
8. They have access to the data category

Answer (score 0):

You can double check:

1. Your user has Knowledge User checkbox activated
2. Your profile: Manage Salesforce Knowledge, Share internal Knowledge articles externally and Allow View Knowledge checkboxes as true.

Comment: I have only one knowledge user license which is being used by one user to manage all articles and stuff.

I just want to give read ability to the articles. So i m trying to display the articles for external user. But the tab is not visible no matter what i do